# Does integrability on whole line imply integrability on subset?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does the integrability of $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}_{\mathbb{R}},m_L)$ imply that \begin{equation}\int_A f\,\mathrm{d}m_L\end{equation}
exists and is finite for $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, without further conditions?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is measurable, then $\int_A |f| \le \int |f|$, since $|f(x)|1_A(x) \le |f(x)|$ for all $x$.